# Helix 3D - Transparent without colour

Tags: wpf, colors, 3d, transparent, helix-3d-toolkit

I am new to Helix and trying to create a simple box with transparent at run time with C#. I can see the box showing with transparency but there is no colour on the box. I dont know if i did anything wrong in my small piece of code:

```
Objects = new ObservableCollection<Visual3D>();
Objects.Add(new GridLinesVisual3D());
var color = Color.FromArgb(0x80, Colors.Red.R, Colors.Red.G, Colors.Red.B);
var b = new BoxVisual3D()
{
Width = 10,
Length = 10,
Height = 10,
};

var brush = new SolidColorBrush();
brush.Color = color;
b.Fill = brush;
Objects.Add(b);
```

Thank you very much in advance.
Best regards

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this, but I could not. I see a cube with transparent red faces which seems correct to me. Maybe there was a bug in Helix which has been fixed since the question was asked? I suggest you try again with a current version of Helix and check if the question still applies.